# cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple infinite loading

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm using [cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple](https://github.com/twogate/cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple) and I don't have a physical ios device so I always use emulator with xcode to debug my code.
I'm triyng to implement SignIn With Apple.

I've turn on "SignIn With Apple" inside capabilities in Xcode and I write the demo code in my app:

```
window.cordova.plugins.SignInWithApple.signin(
  { requestedScopes: [0, 1] },
  function(succ){
    console.log(succ)
    alert(JSON.stringify(succ))
  },
  function(err){
    console.error(err)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
  }
)
```

If I tried to login with Apple Account the first two steps works good, but the third one after I insert the password remain in infinite loop loading. I don't find anything in the documentation. What could be the problem?
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]